Windows cmd works but Powershell fails to get similar output
The below command works on Windows Command prompt cmd
D:\Git-Runners\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\mvn -f "D:\Git-Runners\myrepo\pom.xml" help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout

Output:
super-portal
sharing snapshot just to showcase i m indeed getting the output from command prompt:

I wish to execute the same command using github workflow powershell and i try the below:
  PRE_RELEASE:
    runs-on: "selfhosted-windows"

    steps:

      - name: Release to DEV
        shell: powershell
        run: |
          $newmvnhome = "D:\Git-Runners\apache-maven-3.8.1"
          $repopath = "D:\Git-Runners\myrepo"
          $ARTIFACTCMD = "$newmvnhome\bin\mvn -f `"$repopath\pom.xml`" help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout"
          Write-Host "ARTIFACTCMD: $ARTIFACTCMD"
          $ARTIFACT = Invoke-Expression $ARTIFACTCMD
          Write-Host "ARTIFACT is $ARTIFACT"

I do not get any errors but the output is blank.
Output: ARTIFACT is 
I tried suggestion from this post. Like below but they did not help either.
$ARTIFACTCMD = '& D:\Git-Runners\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\mvn -f "D:\Git-Runners\myrepo\pom.xml" help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout'
Write-Host "ARTIFACTCMD: $ARTIFACTCMD"

$ARTIFACTCMD = "& D:\Git-Runners\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\mvn -f 'D:\Git-Runners\myrepo\pom.xml' help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout"
Write-Host "ARTIFACTCMD: $ARTIFACTCMD"

It opened a new prompt like a popup windows prints the contents of pom.xml and closes with errors in no time. The output remains blank as shared below.
Update: Upon suggestion by @mklement0 I m now getting the correct output however in a new pop terminal and not the terminal that executes Invoke-Expression. See anspshot below.


Also, according to docs, "This cmdlet returns no output of its own, but the invoked command may return output.". Make sure the command runs successfully on its own.

@Azeem i did try the suggestion in the link you shared and updated the original post with snapshots but powershell fails to deliver the output. Infact it opens a popup that runs, fails and auto closes in no time. I could see the popup  printing all the contents  of the pom.xml instead of executing the command and showing just the output.

Unfortunately, a long-standing PowerShell bug, present up to at least PowerShell (Core) v7.4.x, causes --prefixed arguments that also contain . to be broken into two arguments. The simplest workaround is to place ``` directly before the argument See the linked duplicate and GitHub issue #6291 for details.

However, because you're formulating your command inside a "..." string, you must use \``.

As for no output getting stored in $ARTIFACTCMD: capturing an external program's output is limited to its stdout output by default; if only stderr output is produced (due to the aforementioned bug, in this case), nothing is captured. To also capture stderr output, append 2>&1 to the call.

@mklement0 i m on powershell version 5.1.17
Can u give me the corrected command to try ... i tried adding  a backtick before each of the  hyphens - in the command argument but that too does not work.

$ARTIFACTCMD = "$newmvnhome\bin\mvn -f \"$repopath\pom.xml`" help:evaluate ``-Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout". Note that it's only -Dexpression=...that needs the backticks, because the.in its value is what triggers the bug. Alternatively, replace``-Dexpression=project.artifactIdwith'-Dexpression=project.artifactId'`

@mklement0 with this suggestion the error and display of the XML is gone and I could see the right output in the popup shell that appears.
$ARTIFACTCMD = "$newmvnhome\bin\mvn -f "$repopath\pom.xml" help:evaluate ``-Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout"
However, how can I capture the output of the execution in $ARTIFACT = Invoke-Expression $ARTIFACTCMD ??

Assuming that the command is otherwise correct and produces stdout output, $ARTIFACT = Invoke-Expression $ARTIFACTCMD should work as-is (stores stdout output as individual lines, with two or more lines resulting in an array). If it (also) produces stderr output (possibly because there are other problems with your command line), use $ARTIFACT = Invoke-Expression "$ARTIFACTCMD 2>&1". If that doesn't help you resolve your problem, please ask a new question focused on just the remaining problem.

@mklement0 The output is in the new launched popup terminal while the terminal where the Invoke-Expression is executed simply does not print anything. Let me see if i can share snapshot of the execution.

This now sounds like a separate problem, which I suggest you ask about in a focused manner in a new question. Personally, I cannot help further, as I'm not familiar with GitHub Actions.
